# Count by day and uniqueness

Tags: sql

Have the following table

Table A

```
ID   Username   Role  SYS_CREATION_DATE
```

In that table a username can be there multiple times with different rows.   So data could be:

```
ID   Username   Role  SYS_CREATION_DATE
--------------------------------------------------
1    JoeSmuck    5    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
2    JoeSmuck    4    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
3    MaryLamb    5    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
4    MaryLamb    4    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
5    MickeyM     5    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
6    MickeyM     4    4-DEC-2017 08.00.00000000 AM
```

Trying to figure out the SQL statement to find that for the 4th of Dec, three users are registered

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Always 08.00.000000 time?

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT`

```
  SELECT SYS_CREATION_DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT username)
  FROM TableA
  GROUP BY SYS_CREATION_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date looks like it has a time component.  You should get rid of it.  The following works in some databases:

```
select trunc(sys_creation_date), count(distinct username)
from t
group by trunc(sys_creation_date);
```

Different databases have different functions for removing the time component.